# Debug custom rewrite provider

Tags: visual-studio, iis, url-rewriting

This is the first time I'm trying to write my own rewrite provider, I normally do web development. Has been built based on this tutorial http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/developing-a-custom-rewrite-provider-for-url-rewrite-module

Is there a way I can debug the code so I can insert breakpoints and follow the code through as it runs?

Thanks

Comment: did you find solution for this? I am also stuck and need help to debug the provider code

Comment: I'm afraid not. It just took a lot of trial and error. Sorry can't be more help. Good luck.

Comment: finally did it. we need to attach the w3wp.exe of managed code. Also we can check if all DLL loaded in Debug->Winddows->Modules window, I agree lot of trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

I allways use some kind of logging , event log or txt file.
It is only option if zou dont have VS on that machine